# Update Trigger SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view, triggers, sql-update

I have created a view in SQL server 2008 which consists of the joining of about 5 different tables to access the data i need.

How would i create an update trigger to update a field within this view?  So for example if i wanted to update all first names to peter if the last name is smith.

```
If Fname = peter
update Sname to Smith
end if
```

Many thanks in advance

UPDATE
this is what i have so far

```
CREATE TRIGGER SurName
   ON  ViewCustomer
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
if FName= 'Peter'
BEGIN
    update ViewCustomer set SName= 'Smith'
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

END
GO
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific problem do you have? Have you read what the [documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(v=sql.100).aspx) about creating triggers on views?

Comment: hi Pondlife, i have updated my question with the code i have tried, but it shows an error saying it can find my view 'ViewCustomer'. "The object 'ViewCustomer' does not exist or is invalid for this operation."

Comment: Can you show us view `ViewCustomer`?

Comment: You need to use an instead of trigger and update the underlying tables based upon the rows in the virtual tables "inserted" and "deleted"

Comment: As I said, have you read what the documentation says about adding triggers to views? It clearly states that only `INSTEAD OF` triggers can be created on views, so you should not expect an `AFTER` trigger to work. What happens if you re-write your trigger as an `INSTEAD OF` trigger? Have you also read what the documentation [has to say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956(v=sql.100).aspx) about updatable views?

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job.

Table and view definitions.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
  (ID int,
   FName varchar(200),
   SName varchar(200),
   RoleID int);

CREATE TABLE CustomerRole
 (RID int,
  Name varchar(100));

CREATE VIEW ViewCustomer AS
SELECT *
FROM Customer JOIN CustomerRole on RoleID = RID;
```

Trigger definition.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ViewCustomerTrigger ON ViewCustomer
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE Customer 
SET FName = I.FName,
    SName = CASE I.FName WHEN 'Peter' THEN 'Smith' ELSE I.SName END,
    RoleID = I.RoleID
FROM INSERTED I JOIN Customer C ON I.ID = C.ID

UPDATE CustomerRole
SET Name = I.Name
FROM INSERTED I JOIN CustomerRole R ON I.RID = R.RID
END
GO
```

Sample data

```
INSERT INTO Customer (ID, FName, SName, RoleID)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Wayne', 1);

INSERT INTO Customer (ID, FName, SName, RoleID)
VALUES (2, 'Jack', 'Jackson', 1);

INSERT INTO CustomerRole (RID, Name)
VALUES (1, 'Manager');
```

This update will cause the trigger to update the SName to 'Smith'

```
UPDATE ViewCustomer
SET FName = 'Peter'
WHERE ID = 1
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01a69/1/0) is a SQLFiddle for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an INSTEAD OF trigger for views. You can check on:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188601.aspx